# Access text of list item using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, find

I need to get the text of a list item in my menu but don't seem able to grab it.

This is how the menu in my div looks:

```
 <div id='imgbox_1' class='unlocked'>
    <div id="imgbox_1_menu" class="menu">
    <ul class='dropdown'>
     <li><a href='#'> ▼ </a>
      <ul class='sub_menu'> 
          <li class='locker'>Lock</li>
          <li class='delete'>Delete</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the text of the `li` with the `locker` class, using this:

`$('#imgbox_1').children('.menu').find('locker').text();`

But that doesn't return anything. If I try `...find('locker').html()` it says "undefined". How do I get the text, i.e. "Lock" in this case? I need to change it to once it's clicked but I can't even access it. The menu with these list items is created dynamically, it isn't there to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need dot . for class selector. You missed dot before locker

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxEre/)**

```
$('#imgbox_1').children('.menu').find('.locker').text();
```

Or

```
$('#imgbox_1  .menu  .locker').text();
```

Or, if hierarch is not important

```
$('.locker').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the period **`.`** which is the class selector.

```
.find('.locker')
```